# RangeError [BITFIELD_INVALID]: Invalid bitfield flag or number: undefined

Tags: discord, bots

**I have a discord perm error does any1 know how to fix this**
CODE:

```
import DiscordJS, { Intents } from 'discord.js'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()

const client = new DiscordJS.Client({
   intents: [
       Intents.FLAGS.MESSAGE_CREATE,
       Intents.FLAGS.MESSAGE_UPDATE,
   ]
})

client.on('ready', () => {
   console.log('Bot is online')
})

client.on('messageCreate', (message) =>{
   if (message.content === 'test') {
       message.reply({
           content: 'Test is working'
       })
   }
})

client.login(process.env.TOKEN)
```

ERROR:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2uzR.png

Thanks!

Comment: If my answer worked, make sure to mark it as the best answer! You can also upvote if you are not the owner.

Answer (score 0):

The error says that your intents are invalid. There are not event names. See the full list of intents [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Intents?scrollTo=s-FLAGS). It looks like you need `GUILD` and `GUILD_MESSAGES`. Your code would look like this:

```js
import DiscordJS, { Intents } from 'discord.js';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

const client = new DiscordJS.Client({
    intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
    ]
});

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is online');
});

client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
    if (message.content === 'test') {
        message.reply({ content: 'Test is working' });
    }
});

client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

**Hoped this helped!**